# How do I get my MouseListener method to work in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm very new to java and I'm making a simple pixel art maker. I copied a for loop to draw circles.
I was doing the mouse clicking method. I did it so that when I click, it prints "Left" or "Right".

This is the grid system: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Graphics/Shape/Draw_a_grid_by_drawing_lines_in_Java.htm

This is my MouseEvent system I used:

https://github.com/DevonCrawford/A-Pathfinding-Visualization/blob/master/src/Frame.java

The only problem is that it doesn't print the "Left" and "Right". Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Main extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 600, 584);
    window.getContentPane().add(new Main());
//    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);

  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int rows = 20;

    int cols = 20;
    int width = getSize().width;
    int height = getSize().height;

    // draw the rows
    int rowHt = height / (rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      g.drawLine(0, i * rowHt, width, i * rowHt);

    // draw the columns
    int rowWid = width / (cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
      g.drawLine(i * rowWid, 0, i * rowWid, height);

  }

  public void MapCalculations(MouseEvent e) { 
    // If left mouse button is clicked
    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
        System.out.println("Left");

    } 
    // If right mouse button is clicked
    else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
        System.out.println("Right");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    MapCalculations(e);
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    MapCalculations(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse listener methods are never being called because the framework doesn't know when to call them.

Try adding the mouse listener to your `window` object in the main method as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    Main myMain = new Main();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 600, 584);
    window.getContentPane().add(myMain);
//    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);    
    window.addMouseListener(myMain);
  }
```

Comment: yeah, I see that now

Comment: Don't feel dumb, I can't tell you how many times I forgot to actually add the listener...

Answer (score 0):

The method is never called because you never add a mouse listener to anything.

You probably want, in the Main constructor,

```
this.addMouseListener(this);
```

You really should respect the Java naming conventions, too. Methods start with a lowercase charater. And you shouldn't use `paint()` to draw on Swing components. Read [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Don't disagree with the answer, but the first line 'You never add a mouse listener to anything' can be read as 'You _should_ never add a mouse listener to anything' (how I initially read it, and was then confused by the advice on the next line...).  I'd consider a rewording to make the intended meaning clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip.  Implement your mouseListener in an inner class.

```java
    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         MapCalculations(e);
       }
       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         MapCalculations(e);
       }
    }
```

Then use an instance of that to process mouse events.  The inner class still has
access to your enclosing class's values.

```
window.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
```

By doing it this way you don't need to have all those empty methods.  Also, you can use
the same mouse listener class for `mouseMotionListener` requirements since the `MouseAdapter` class has empty methods for both interfaces of `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`